# Toggle between TableViewCells, setting accessoryView and Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i am building a social App, where you can send messages - its not a chatting app, only sending objects ( i am learning to code). I want to select only one friend from my tableView and send the message to him. I also want to add my cell.accessoryView only on one cell, the selected one. When i hit another row, the last cells accessoryView gets deselected. Also disable multiple touches on one row = if i select one friend, the only way how to deselect him, is to select another cell. I also created a string and i want to add only the cell.textLabel.text from the selected cell, if i select another cell, old info gets deleted and new info added. I tried a lot of stuff, but nothing works and i didn't find any tutorial or answer :(. Does anybody have an idea, how to do this? Thank you very much for answers:

This is the lat code i tried, it works but if i toggle more than 2 times it gets corrupted

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

`UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

//checkmark is my image for custom checkmark

if (cell.accessoryView == checkmark)
{
    cell.accessoryView = nil;
}
else
{
    cell.accessoryView = checkmark;
}`

}

Comment: i have edited my answer once check it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this method in your tableview class

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell * currentCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UITableViewCell * oldCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: oldIndexPath];

    oldCell.accessoryView = nil;
    currentCell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkMark"]];


    oldIndexPath = indexPath; //  instance Variable NSIndexPath * oldIndexPath;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me :( i am using cell.accesoryView = myCheckmark and the checkmark doesn't go off when another cell is selected

Comment: post your code what you have tried,in your question

Comment: Works much better, but still after 3 touches, it gets corrupted and then i have to touch my cell twice to get selected

Comment: Then i have mistakes somewhere in my code :) but thanks for answer!